# Can a single serial port be opened by multiple processes?

Tags: macos, arduino, serial-port

Or can a single serial port be redirected to two "virtual" serial ports which, in turn, can each be opened by separate processes?

Or is there a better/easier way to solve this problem I'm having?

Here's my problem. I'm trying to make a laser harp similar to [this one](http://makezine.com/projects/build-two-octave-laser-harp/). But unlike that one, mine sends MIDI commands over the serial port to my mac.

I also need to send non-MIDI serial data back from my mac to the laser harp. These are custom commands that adjust the mirror angle, light sensitivity etc.

The problem is I use one process to receive the data on the mac and I use a different process to send the data. Hence the question, can two processes open a single serial port?

I don't want to combine these two processes into one, mainly because they are pre-existing applications I didn't write. The one that reads data from the laserharp is [hairless-midi](http://projectgus.github.io/hairless-midiserial/). The other one is just just a plain terminal (I use the one that came with the Arduino IDE).

Note only the terminal needs to write to the serial port. Both processes will read from the serial port.

Comment: You shouldn't open a serial port twice, because almost always the access to that resource is exclusive. On Windows I found a program called hub4com, but I couldn't make it work very well. But.. It's windows only. Maybe you will be able to find an analogous product for Linux/osx, but in the end I think the best option is to make a single program merging the two data parts (or even two separate programs which instead of writing on a port write in a pipe, then a third one which joins everything). Or, in the end, put two serial ports (there are FTDI chips with multiple ports (so 1USB -> X serials)